# Schedule siumlation from Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to run a code in java. The input to java code is .xml file. I have 42 xml files ready and I want to schedule the run one after another using matlab. I mean instead of doing by hand I want the matlab to control simulation and start from the first xml file, give it as input to java and tells java to store the simulation result in specific folder. 
Any idea?

Comment: Why MATLAB? If you know MATLAB well, this might be a simple way to do it, but if you need to ask how to do it anyway, why not use a language that is meant for this, something like a shell script?

Comment: @ Cris Luengo As you said that is because I am familiar with matlab. But if you have any other suggestion pls share (shell script?)